# show that set $A=\{x\in X\mid f(x)\le g(x)\}$ is closed in X

Tags: general-topology

let Y be an ordered set in the order topology.let X be a topological space and let $f,g:{X\to Y}$ be continuous function.

show that the set $A=\{x\in X\mid f(x)\le g(x)\}$ is closed in X.
I used the complement A and Hasdorf, but I didn't get anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

note that in $Y\times Y$ with the product topology, $\{(y_1, y_2)| y_1 \le y_2\}$ is closed, and $(f,g):X\rightarrow Y\times Y$ is continuous, since each factor is.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p \notin A$, so that $f(p) > g(p)$ in $Y$.

Case 1: if there exists a $y_0 \in Y$ with $f(p) > y_0 > g(p)$ then check that

$U = f^{-1}[(y_0, \rightarrow)] \cap g^{-1}[(\leftarrow, y_0)]$ contains $p$ and is a subset of $A$, showing that $p$ is an interior point of $A$.

Case 2: no such $y_0$ exists and in that case

$U = f^{-1}[(g(p), \rightarrow)] \cap g^{-1}[\leftarrow, f(p)]$ has the same properties and also $p$ is an interior point of $A$.

So $A$ is open. (In both cases $U$ is open because we use the order topology on $Y$ and $f,g$ are continuous.)

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ and $g$ are continuous, what can you say about $f-g : X \to Y$ ? Thus, can you express $A$ as the reverse image of $f-g$ of a suitable closed subset of $Y$ ?

Comment: what is $f-g$ in an (arbitrary) ordered set?

Comment: You're right. You have to adapt this proof.